Pivot median fails to be calculated because of column formatting
I am very new to the macro world (first post here) so I apologize if there is an obvious solution that I'm missing. I've also been using the record macro feature so the script below might be a bit messy.
Goal: create a macro that automates data cleaning and creates a pivot table that calculates medians and other statistics
Problem: median fails to calculate for one of my columns. The error messages is: "MEDIAN does not support expressions of type string/boolean/date".
Details of what my macro does and what I've tried:
I wrote a macro that first organizes my data (continuous values) and then cleans up data by removing any values of zero or 40 from a particular column. However, this column is mostly blank after the the cleaning step (see metric2 in example of data below). Lastly, the macro automatically generates a pivot table with medians of a handful of columns. The column with mostly blanks (metric2) fails to generate a median in the pivot table with the error message described above.
The data organization steps involve a vlookup to seek out the correct values from another sheet, then a copy and paste as values of the entire column to break the vlookup in case the unique identifier for the vlookup gets changed.
This is what I use to remove all 40s and zeros in the column:
    Range("Y:Y").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="40", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2

    Range("X:AB").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2

After the data cleanup, I try to format the columns to numbers (see below). I check my excel and indeed the cells in the column of concern is formatted as numbers, but the median function still fails to calculate the median of one particular column and outputs the error that "MEDIAN does not support expressions of type string/boolean/date". The other columns generate medians just fine.
    Range("S:AB").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0"

This is a sample of the data that I'm working with. Metric2 is the column that struggles to generate medians.
Metric1 Metric2
-1.2    
-0.8    
-0.8    
-0.7    
-0.9    
-1.9    
-1.6    
-0.6    
-0.7    
-1.2    
-1.1    
-1.7    
-1.2    
-0.6    
-1.7    
-1.7    
-0.9    
-1.0    
-0.9    
-1.0    
-1.2    
-1.3    
-1.0    
-1.9    
-1.0    
-1.2    
-1.1    
-1.3    
-1.3    
-1.1    
-1.1    
-1.2    
-0.9    
-1.3    
-1.2    
-1.4    
-1.3    
-0.9    
-1.2    
-0.7    
-1.1    
-0.8    
20.5    29.6
-0.7    
-1.2    
-0.3    
-0.7    
-0.9    

I checked my data - all columns start out formatted as numbers and also end up as numbers after the cleaning. When I apply a filter manually to the Metric2 column, I notice that excel wants to sort the original column as numbers. After the cleaning step (leaving only a few numbers behind, with mostly blank cells), and then applying a filter manually, excel wants to sort Metric2 alphabetically. Unsure if this means that the column is actually formatted as something else even though every cell in the column (except for the title) shows formatting as numbers.

This means that you're dealing with text-that-looks-like-a-number. Applying formatting doesn't change the underlying value. Note that "40" and "0" are text, not numbers. You need to convert the values from text to numbers.

As an FYI, it's highly recommended that you avoid using .Select and .Activate.

Thanks for the feedback, let me look for ways to force the formatting to numbers. The macro already has a command to format the columns to numbers but it seems not to be working.

Your column B contains text strings that look like numbers.  A clue is that with default formatting numbers sit at the right side of a cell and strings sit at the left. The position of "29.6" is consistent with it being a text string. Apply =VALUE( ) to the string to get a number. Or swap out the string delimiters enclosing it " for nothing.

Wow, this community is incredible. Someone went into my post to help me edit the formatting. Thank you Tim.

I will try out =VALUE().
I'm not sure how to reply to comments, but why is using .select and .activate a bad thing? I will also look this up because there's probably a ton of background info i'm missing. Thank you for the advice!

I don't see in your code where you are calculating MEDIAN. And the MEDIAN worksheet function should ignore text in the data, making me wonder if your problem lies elsewhere. And column formatting does not affect the data in the column, only how it is displayed.

@RonRosenfeld I suspected my problem was in the data formatting so I didn't post the part of the code containing the median function:
ActiveWorkbook.Model.ModelMeasures.Add "Median of Metric2", ActiveWorkbook.Model.ModelTables("ControlTable1"), "MEDIAN([Metric2])", ActiveWorkbook.Model.ModelFormatDecimalNumber(False, 1)

@JYFung OK, now your error message makes sense to me. You are not using the Excel MEDIAN function; rather you are using the DAX MEDIAN function. The latter does have an issue with text strings in the data. The former does not.

Fixed by using suggestion from @MartinBrown
I modified my vlookup functions with =VALUE() to make sure that all data taken from another sheet are converted into values:
Range("S2").Formula = "=VALUE(VLOOKUP(R2,Target!R:S,2,FALSE))"

Thank you all! My next goal now is to destroy all the .select and .activate
